# Keeping hyperlinks functional after moving directory

Tags: worksheet-function

I currently have a worksheet in which I have several hyperlinks to folders. I am attempting to have the hyperlinks automatically change when the root path changes.

I have figured out how to have a formula create a hyperlink in the root directory where the file is located, but cannot figure out how to point to directories beyond that. Here is the formula I am using currently:

=HYPERLINK(MID(CELL("filename"),1,FIND("[",CELL("filename"))-1),"Root Folder")

This will correctly open whichever folder I place it in (for example: "C:\Invoices\2012"). However, I also want additional cells to open further folders in the path (for example: "C:\Invoices\2012\Box 1" or "C:\Invoices\2012\Box 1\Folder 1")

I feel like I've almost got this, but I can't figure out the last bit. Any help please?

Comment: Can "filename" contain a relative path, e.g. "\Box 1\file.csv" [with or without initial backslash]?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out another method to keep the hyperlinks as relative links rather than absolute links, and this resolved the issue.

Simply a matter of File > Options > Advanced, and unchecking the "Save external link values" under the "When calculating this workbook" header.